# 2002 Ford Ranger transmission issue

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, vibration, ranger

I have a standard Ford Ranger that shimmies when I take off in first real bad so I take off and 2nd and it shimmies less please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What do you mean by shimmies?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems like it's a clutch issue ... quite possibly in need of a new one. If the clutch was overheated in the past, it may have gained some heat cracks in it, which would cause the vibrations. The only real way to fix it is through replacement.